# Deploy the directories to remote windows server

Tags: windows, command-line, msbuild, teamcity

Am using Teamcity as my CI, after checking out a repo from Github i need to deploy the files and directories to one of the remote windows machine

Note: Both my Teamcity agent and remote machine are having windows OS

Please help me to achieve the same with command line or by any of the plugins.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TeamCity Deployer plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin) to gather artifacts and deploy them to a network share or FTP.

Create new network share on your target Windows machine and configure correct write permissions for the share and NTFS folder. Use the network share address in TeamCity build configuration. The machine running TeamCity agent must have access to the network share.